# Audio drift when piping sound to the speakers in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, stream, pipe

In one of the programs I'm developing where eliminating echo is a big deal, other developers have noticed in the program there is a drift in the echo. To see where the problem is I tore apart the code, and finally found that no matter what I do, the audio will drift in Node.js.

**Steps to reproduce**

**1.** Have a .wav audio recording to use for sampling.

**2.** Have an audio recording program to record the output from the speakers and point a microphone on the speakers for direct recording.

**3.** First, record the .wav being played using a normal audio player application. Analyze the two files and note that there is no audio drift in the two.

**4.** Create the following script in Node.js

```
var process = require( 'process' );
var argv = require('minimist')( process.argv.slice(2) );
var Speaker = require( 'speaker' );
var fs = require( 'fs' );
var wav = require( 'wav' );

var wavReader = fs.createReadStream( String( argv._[ 0 ] ) )
.pipe( wav.Reader() );

var buffer = null;

wavReader.on( 'format', function( format ) {
    console.log( "Playing wav.", format );
    wavReader.on( 'data', function( chunk ) {
        if( buffer )
            buffer = Buffer.concat( [ buffer, chunk ] );
        else
            buffer = chunk;
    } )
    .on( 'end', function() { 
        new Speaker( format ).write( buffer );
    } );
} );
```

**5.** Do the same recording process as before, but this time record the output of the Node.js script. Note the audio drifts in the recorded versus original file.

This is what I see when I do the above in step 5. In my screenshot, the top is the original .wav file and the bottom is its recorded version after aligning properly at the beginning.
[image: Audio Drift]

I thought that maybe it was the node-speaker module package, so I decided to re-write the code using aplay for alsa.

```
var process = require( 'process' );
var argv = require('minimist')( process.argv.slice(2) );
var fs = require( 'fs' );
var wav = require( 'wav' );
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var wavReader = fs.createReadStream( String( argv._[ 0 ] ) )
.pipe( wav.Reader() );

var buffer = null;

wavReader.on( 'format', function( format ) {
    console.log( "Playing wav.", format );
    var aplay = spawn( 'aplay', [
            "-r", String( format.sampleRate ),
            "-c", String( format.channels ),
            "-f", "S16_LE"
        ]
    );

    wavReader.pipe( aplay.stdin );
} );
```

However, the same audio drift appears in this code *also*. I'm hoping that this isn't a limitation in Node.js and I don't have to switch to C++ to fix this issue. My Node.js version is *v0.10.30*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the same functionality with alas in C. Turns out the issue only occurred when playing 8000Hz audio. I figured that maybe my sound card didn't perform so well with having to resample. I tried the same function on another computer and had no drifting. So it wasn't a Node.js issue after all.